# Docker machine timeout - how to fix without destroying the machine?

Tags: macos, docker, timeout, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm having a recurring problem with Docker Machine - every few days it decides to timeout and I am unable to recover it once this happens.

**Example**

```
docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default            virtualbox   Timeout
```

**Environment Info**

```
uname -a                 Darwin ColeyMBPR 15.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
docker version           1.11.0
docker-machine version   0.7.0
vboxmanage --version     5.0.20r106931
```

**Attempted Solutions**

I've tried the following things in no particular order:

- Restarting the docker machine.
- Running `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`
- Regenerating the certificates `docker-machine regenerate-certs default`
- Restarting my host box.
- Upgrading Docker.
- Reinstalling Docker.
- Upgrading VirtualBox.
- Removing all VirtualBox host-only network devices.

**Hack**

The only thing that's working for me right now is destroying the docker machine and recreating it. This destroys all my images and containers, and it's incredibly time consuming to set it up again.

```
docker-machine rm -y default && docker-machine create -d virtualbox default && eval $(docker-machine env)
```

**Is there anything I can try?** Thanks!

---

**Update: 9th May (Steps to Reproduce)**

I can reliably reproduce this problem with the following steps:

1. Start with a freshly created Docker machine.
2. Use `docker-compose up` to build some containers.
3. Shutdown the computer with the containers running.
4. After reboot the Docker CLI doesn't work due to the Docker machine timing out.

Comment: does docker-machine ssh default works?

Comment: so commands like docker ps doesnt work? but ssh works?

Comment: Try switching to the new [docker (beta)](https://beta.docker.com/) solution

Comment: Yeah that's right.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issues. Able to ssh, not able to make it active.

Comment: @jdcaballerov: Upgrading to Docker beta worked for me.

Comment: I tried to poke around and then running `docker-machine upgrade` made everything go away.

Comment: The latest version of Docker doesn't have these issues. :)

Answer (score 25):

This command worked for me with the digitalocean driver:

`docker-machine ls -t 20`

It seems as though the [default timeout of 10 seconds](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ls/) was too short.

Comment: Pity there wasn't an environment variable for this timeout.  A pain to have to add every time (or create aliases / shell functions).

Answer (score 7):

This is usually a problem related to the way you start and stop your machine.

You can solve it using

1. `$ docker-machine stop default`
2. `$ docker-machine start default`
3. `$ docker-machine regenerate-certs default`

Do not use `docker-machine restart default` because it will not refresh your networking configs.

Comment: did not work for me but more importantly...stop/start and regen took a long time.

Answer (score 6):

Check if you are are using a proxy or VPN!

None of the above suggestions worked for me until I turned off my VPN and suddenly:

```
docker-machine.exe ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376           v19.03.5
```

Comment: What a lifesave! I had my VPN on and was figuring this out for the last 2 hours!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9

This worked for me - my docker machine is back to the  Running state

1. `$ docker-machine restart`
2. `$ eval $(docker-machine env)`

Answer (score 1):

So far I have a bit of a hacky solution - this fixes the docker machine but destroys all containers and images.

**Script: rebuild-machine.sh**

```
docker-machine rm -y default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
docker-machine stop default
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "Forwarding App 1,tcp,127.0.0.1,3000,,3000"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "Forwarding App 2,tcp,127.0.0.1,3001,,3001"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "Forwarding App 3,tcp,127.0.0.1,3004,,3004"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "Forwarding App 4,tcp,127.0.0.1,3005,,3005"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "Forwarding App 5,tcp,127.0.0.1,3006,,3006"
VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "Forwarding App 6,tcp,127.0.0.1,8081,,8081"
docker-machine start default
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

**Explanation**

- Destroys the default docker machine, containers and images.
- Creates a new docker machine on VirtualBox and stops it so we can modify VirtualBox.
- Adds port forwarding for various applications on VirtualBox.
- Starts the docker machine.
- Ensures the Terminal is setup for the new IP address of the docker machine.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was very simple.  I was blocking port 2376 with my ufw firewall. Docker-machine needs this port open to connect to the remote.

[I found the answer to my problem in on this page:](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and my containers were not destroyed:

1. Opened Oracle virtual box and paused the VM
2. Restarted the VM on docker machine

`$ docker-machine restart default`

- docker version: 1.12.3
- docker-machine version: 0.8.2, build e18a919

Comment: Hi @tej, if you upgrade to the latest version of Docker this is no longer a problem. You no longer need to use Virtual Box at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened virtualbox and closed and start all vm manually/. State is `running` again

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest version of Docker, this issue was resolved a long time ago.

Comment: i have Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3

this problem occurs whenever i put my linux mint to hibernate

Answer (score 0):

My problem was very trivial - I did the `docker machine ls` command right after restarting a docker machine, so it was not running yet, and that caused a timeout.